# Using chunk template engine in android with custom tags

Tags: java, android, template-engine, chunk-templates

I am trying to use chunk in android. I need something like this:

Suppose,

Following are tags.

**tags:** {"world":"WORLD", "c": "Dennis Ritchie", "apple":"JOBS" }

**Input:** HELLO {{ world }}, C is written by **{{ c }}**, while java is written by {{ java }}, hola.

**Output:** HELLO WORLD, C is written by Dennis Ritchie, while java is written **by, hola.**

In short

1. I need a custom delimiter like, {{ string }}
   i.e.

   DEFAULT_TAG_START = "{{";

   DEFAULT_TAG_END ="}}";
2. While if input contains tag which is not specified, then it should be replaced by empty.

I tried & stuck at following,

```
public String process(String msg) {

   Chunk c = new Chunk();               
   c.append(msg);
   c.set("apple", "JOBS");
   c.set("c", "Dennis Ritchie");
   c.set("world", "WORLD");
   return c.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Chunk template engine does not support alternate tag syntax at the moment.  Also, whitespace within tag markers is not ignored/discarded.

However, there is a possible bridge solution here.  Chunk tags that are not provided will default to empty as long as the tag name is followed by a colon.

So your input must change to valid Chunk syntax:

```
HELLO {$world:}, C is written by {$c:}, while java is written by {$java:}, hola.
```

If your template syntax is not flexible (eg, you have a library of pre-existing templates, or you just really dislike the native tag syntax) you could add a pre-processing step to transform `{{ this }}` into `{$this:}` before appending it to the Chunk template.

The Chunk library even provides a convenience function that will do this for you (although you may need to reimplement it if the input is inconsistent with whitespace).

```
import com.x5.template.TemplateSet;

...

Chunk c = new Chunk();

String template = TemplateSet.convertTags(msg, "{{ ", " }}", "{$", ":}");
c.append(template);

c.set("apple", "JOBS");
c.set("c", "Dennis Ritchie");
c.set("world", "WORLD");
return c.toString();
```